# Function returns inside loops?

Tags: python-3.x, function, return

How do return statements of a function work inside for loops? See my code below for what got me thinking about this.

It is like a game of scrabble. You get given n letters (we'll call it a hand), and the aim is to make a word out of your hand. The hand is in the form of a dictionary, like so:

`yellow = {'y':1, 'e':1, 'l':2, 'o':1, 'w':1}`

I have written a function called `get_frequency_dict` to transform a string in to this form.

I want to write a function which tells me if the word given is valid or not. I have a list of acceptable words in the variable `word_list`

Call the function: `is_valid_word(word, hand, word_list)` which takes in three inputs.

```
word: string
hand: dictionary (string: int)
word_list: list of lowercase strings
```

So, I wanted to write this function to return True if the word is valid and False if the word is invalid:

```
def is_valid_word(word, hand, word_list):


    word_dict = get_frequency_dict(word.lower())


    if word.lower() in word_list:

        for char in word_dict:
            if (char in hand) and (hand[char] >= word_dict[char]):
                return True
            else:
                return False

    else:
        return False
```

This function seems to work fine with various different inputs, but I'm not quite sure I understand the logic behind the function return in the for loop?

As we loop through the keys in the dictionary (letters), we will get a True or False depending on whether or not the condition is satisfied. So, how does the function know what to return? What if one char returns False and then the next char returns True? Does it instantly return False as soon as it sees one False in the for loop?

The code below makes more sense to me:

```
total_false = 0

    for char in word_dict:
        if (char in hand) and (hand[char] >= word_dict[char]):
            pass
        else:
            total_false += 1

    if word.lower() not in word_list:
        return False
    elif total_false > 0:
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

Does the first segment of code do this "counting" behind the scenes? As in, as soon as we see a False, it returns False?

Comment: if there is a return statement the method execution will stop there only no further execution

Comment: Looking at your code and what you want to do, I would advise you to look into `yield`. This will return a generator object that is like a list.

Comment: @komatiraju032 so in the for loop, it will break out of the function after the first iteration?

Comment: @theman it will stop the loop and exit method if the for loop is inside a method

Comment: @komatiraju032 so the return value of the function is completely dependent on the first character in ```word_dict```?

Comment: @theman yes as per your code

Answer (score 0):

Simply iterate over the list and if you find an error, stop:

```py
def is_valid_word(word, hand, word_list):


    word_dict = get_frequency_dict(word.lower())


    if word.lower() in word_list:

        for char in word_dict:
            if (char in hand) and (hand[char] >= word_dict[char]):
                continue
            else:
                return False #This will stop the function and return false

    else:
        return False #This will do the same


    #At the end, this means that all of the criteria are met, so we return True
    return True
```

As we see, the moment a character doesn't fit the criteria, the function stops and returns `false`. If it passes all the criteria, it returns `true`.